# what is the difference among string, CString, QString?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

I see "CString" in MFC, and "QString" in QT.
what is the difference among string, CString, QString?
Why do not use "string" directly?

Answer (score 2):

They're different variation on string types.

`std::string` is the one from the ISO standard and probably preferred in situations where you want portability. It is required to be provided by all implementations claiming to conform with the standard.

`CString` is, as you say, from MFC (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174288%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)) and will generally only work in that environment. If you're programming exclusively to Windows, you can probably use that. It may have extra features not provided by `std::string`.

Similarly, `QString` is the Qt variation, documented [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html), and is meant to represent strings in programs using Qt. Like `CString`, it's more tightly bound to its environment so may offer efficiencies over `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking around (doing your research for you basically) I found some stuff.

`String`: Does NOT support character encoding, no special functionality vs the others(.) 
`QString`: Plenty of useful functions, some better compatibilities, supports character encoding, default UTF-16(.) 
`CString`: Plenty of useful functions, some better compatibilities, and good for Unicode and Ascii compilation(..), ...

There are also some more things that are not mentioned here, the sources are

. http://blog.rburchell.com/2010/08/strings-and-qt.html 
.. http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?319932-CString-vs-std-string  
... Elsewhere  
.... Built to work better with its own framework

I hope I was helpful, as this is my first post.